# Multiplex akka streams source into two copies

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to cache a streaming source to disk while I'm also sending it out as an `HttpResponse`, i.e. I have a `Source[ByteString,_]` that I want to hand to `HttpEntity`, but I also want to run the same data into a `FileIO.toPath` sink.

```
                       |-> FileIO.toPath
Source[ByteString,_] ->|
                       |-> HttpEntity(contentType, Source[ByteString,_]
```

It seems that `Broadcast` is what I should use for fan-out but from the description, it writes to two sinks and while `FileIO.toPath` is a sink, `HttpEntity` expects a `Source`.

There's also `Source.fromGraph` which looks like it would create a source from a GraphStage, such as a `Broadcast` stage, but I can't quite figure out how I would get the `FileIO` sink in there.

Comment: can you just have one source -> sink for FileIO.toPath and pass source to HttyEntity directly?

Comment: From my experiments, using the source twice runs the source twice, i.e. i'm downloading the source twice rather than multiplexing the single download

Comment: I don't think its achievable because when your HttpEntity takes Source as part of its parameter, it will call run() eventually and at that point your source will be triggered second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`alsoTo`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/alsoTo.html):

```
val originalSource: Source[ByteString, _] = ???
val cachedSource: Source[ByteString, _] = originalSource.alsoTo(FileIO.toPath(/*...*/))
val entity = HttpEntity(contentType, cachedSource)
```

Comment: I started going down that road and it certainly is an answer to my question, unfortunately that did raise more questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437098/triggering-on-fileio-topath-sink-completion